# Pass argument by jquery change method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any idea to my problems?
I have to pass a value from json data on jquery change. My code look like this now :

```
$('#id_user').val(data.id_user).change(data.id_level); // need to pass this id_level
```

And need that `data.id_level` in :

```
$('#id_user').change((howToPassThatIdLevelHere), function(){ // I need the id_level in here
   ...
})
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JSON` object to pass data through event.

```
//Declare of the change event's callback
$('#id_user').change(function(event, eventdata){
    if(typeof eventdata !== 'undefined'){
       var id_level =  eventdata.id_level; //Way to get passing JSON object
    }
});

//Trigger change event with JSON params
$('#id_user').val(data.id_user).trigger("change",{id_level: data.id_level});
```

**Hint:** The `undefined` checking of `eventdata` is required to avoid error occur, when the `change` event triggered by user

Comment: That's not JSON, it's an object.

Comment: @Ronnie Tws Thanks for your answer, but it seem doesnt work to my code. `console.log(id_level)` not giving any value

Comment: @Barmar Any idea how it should go?

Comment: @far1023 The object is only passed when the event is triggered from this code, not when it happens from the user.

Comment: If you want it to be passed when the event is triggered normally, you should specify it when binding the event handler, not when triggering the event.

Comment: I already make changes about the trigger the change event and it's way to receive the passing data. The sequence of the code is also important, required to declared the event after call the trigger.